# Can Android drawable's clip-path layer be rotated?

Tags: android, android-drawable, vector-graphics

I've just starting using clip-paths in vector drawables. I want to rotate the clip-path, but it's not possible to rotate any path without it being in a group, so that it could have pivotX and pivotY properties. However, when put in a group, it doesn't clip paths outside of a group anymore (and so becomes useless). Is there a workaround for this? This is my drawable (in this state, the clipping doesn't work because of what I mentioned):

```
<!-- drawable/bluetooth_audio.xml -->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <group
        android:name="maskGroup"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12">

        <clip-path
            android:name="mask"
            android:pathData="M12,0 V12 H24 V24 H0 V0"/>

    </group>

    <group
        android:name="base"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFF"
            android:pathData="M12.88,16.29L11,18.17V14.41M11,5.83L12.88,7.71L11,9.58M15.71,7.71L10,2
            H9V9.58L4.41,5L3,6.41L8.59,12L3,17.58L4.41,19L9,14.41V22H10L15.71,16.29L11.41,12M19.53,6.71L18.26,8M14.24,12L16.56,14.33C16.84,13.6 17,12.82 17,12C17,11.18 16.84,10.4 16.57,9.68L14.24,12Z"/>
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFF"
            android:pathData="
            M18.26,8
            C18.89,9.18 19.25,10.55 19.25,12
            C19.25,13.45 18.89,14.82 18.26,16
            L19.46,17.22
            C20.43,15.68 21,13.87 21,11.91
            C21,10 20.46,8.23 19.53,6.71
            "
            />

    </group>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually path and clip-path are use for different purpose.

Clip-path : use for get Canvas or say view-port for drawing.

Path : use for render paint on that view-port.

So, don't use clip-path for drawings or animation. If anything you draw outside of clip-path will nt be render or show. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: I saw videos of Android engineers who used clip path to create animations... AFAIK, clip path is used for animation on Lollipop (quick settings icons). If clip path is not the tool I should use, what is? What is the tool for achieving this type of animation?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to animate the changes of a clip-path, if the start and end states both have the same number of pathData steps; maybe instead of "rotating" the clip-path you define the end state of a "rotated" clip-path and then animate the clip-path? The objectAnimator to apply could look like this:

```
<objectAnimator
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="pathData"
android:valueFrom="M18 37 L38 37 L38 37 L18 37 Z"
android:valueTo="M0 0 L56 0 L56 56 L0 56 Z"
android:duration="600"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
android:valueType="pathType" />
```

EDIT: Found this in the Android documentation

The AnimatedStateListDrawable class lets you create drawables that show animations between state changes of the associated view. Some of the system widgets in Android 5.0 use these animations by default. The following example shows how to define an AnimatedStateListDrawable as an XML resource:

The AnimatedStateListDrawable class lets you create drawables that show animations between state changes of the associated view. Some of the system widgets in Android 5.0 use these animations by default. The following example shows how to define an AnimatedStateListDrawable as an XML resource:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myanimstatedrawable.xml -->
<animated-selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
<item android:id="@+id/pressed"
android:drawable="@drawable/drawableP"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:id="@+id/focused"
android:drawable="@drawable/drawableF"
    android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:id="@id/default"
    android:drawable="@drawable/drawableD"/>

<!-- specify a transition -->
<transition android:fromId="@+id/default"
android:toId="@+id/pressed">
    <animation-list>
        <item android:duration="15"
android:drawable="@drawable/dt1"/>
        <item android:duration="15"
android:drawable="@drawable/dt2"/>
        ...
    </animation-list>
</transition>
...
</animated-selector>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedStateListDrawable.html

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions